# RSpec method questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing

I am pretty new to Rails and am having trouble understanding some of the structure.

I am following the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec%3arspec_integration_tests) and see code like the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Users" do

  describe "signup" do

    describe "failure" do

      it "should not make a new user" do
        visit signup_path
        fill_in "Name",         :with => ""
        fill_in "Email",        :with => ""
        fill_in "Password",     :with => ""
        fill_in "Confirmation", :with => ""
        click_button
        response.should render_template('users/new')
        response.should have_selector("div#error_explanation")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to now make similar tests, but I don't know where to begin.  I tried to find documentation for the "visit" method on the internet, but with no success.  Is it part of Rails' test suite? RSpec? How would I go about answering this question for myself, as well as gaining a good understanding of integration tests?  Is there a thorough tutorial that I can use?

Comment: Looks like it is in Webrat??  Too many things going on at once.  Is there any "comprehensive" tutorial for integration testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is either a method of Webrat or Capybara. Take a look at the method list here: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/DSL#

In general, I find that testing is the worst explained part of rails. Tonnes of things to test, differing philosophies how to test them and dozens of tools for each all with crazy names. I found this railscast particularly helpful in understanding some of what you are looking at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it's webrat.

I'd use Capybara though.

See there first for Rspec and Rspec + Capybara:

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=✓&search=Rspec

Then the Rspec book is really good.

Answer (score 0):

The **visit** method is part of [Webrat](https://github.com/brynary/webrat)

Where to begin with Rspec? - I remember starting with this article few years back. Might be useful to you although it's old. - [Simple Tutorials For Learning BDD and RSpec](http://jimmyzimmerman.com/blog/2007/11/simple-tutorials-for-learning-bdd-and-rspec.html) and this article from IBM - [Behavior-driven testing with RSpec](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-rspec/)

Regarding integration testing, you might want to check [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) too. Head on to Railcasts for a few episodes of Cucumber.

The Rspec book is highly recommended.